# Documenting a streaming POST in Swagger

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger

How would I document an `InputStream` path parameter as `List<Person>` for Swagger? ApiPath does not seem to have request and requstContainer args. Thanks in advance.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/V1/person/batch")
    public void postPersonBatch(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        try (MappingIterator<Person> people = reader.readValues(in)) {
            people.forEachRemaining(writer::write);
        }
    }
```